# How can "burden" in Acts 15:28–29 and Matthew 11:28 be reconciled?

Tags: sin, gospel-of-matthew, christian-living, textual-discrepancies, acts

[Acts 15:28–29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+15%3A28-29&version=NIV) (NIV):

> It seemed good to the Holy Spirit and to us not to burden you with
>   anything beyond the following requirements: You are to abstain from
>   food sacrificed to idols, from blood, from the meat of strangled
>   animals and from sexual immorality.

[Matthew 11:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+11%3A28&version=NIV):

> "Come to me, all you who are weary and burdened, and I will give you
>   rest".

The word 'burden' in Acts witnessed by Holy Spirit and used by Jesus in Matthew seems to mean the same thing, though I haven't done a Greek word study yet.

Wouldn't the combination of these scriptures give license to sin (in human meaning) if it is not violating human rights and legal demands?

Comment: Kindly do not recommend me to refer this [Reformed perspective on “It seemed good to the Holy Spirit and to us”](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11682/reformed-perspective-on-it-seemed-good-to-the-holy-spirit-and-to-us-acts-152) since it doesn't focus on my question.

Comment: You should specify what perspective from which you would like to receive answers in your question then; otherwise you'll get a wide variety of opinions (and probably end up with a closed post).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I belong to a new covenant church who believes in salvation is by faith and grace alone. So I asked in the perspective of the current legalism churches who force tithing, head-covering & other rituals.

Comment: "legalism churches" is  painting with a pretty broad brush.

Answer (score 6):

Well, actually in Greek Bible these words are different.

In Acts 15:28-29:

> ἔδοξεν γὰρ τω̨̃ πνεύματι τω̨̃ ἁγίω̨ καὶ ἡμι̃ν μηδὲν πλέον
>   ἐπιτίθεσθαι ὑμι̃ν **βάρος** πλὴν τούτων τω̃ν ἐπάναγκες

i.e. word **βάρος**, that could mean also "*weight*"

and in Matthew 11:28:

> δευ̃τε πρός με πάντες οἱ κοπιω̃ντες καὶ **πεφορτισμένοι** κἀγὼ
>   ἀναπαύσω ὑμα̃ς

where word **πεφορτισμένοι** could be translated as to be "*overburden*".

So the meaning of word "***burdened***" in your variant of translation is actually different.
If In *Acts 15:28* it means some kind of obedience, while in *Matthew 11:28* it means a state of man, when he is overburden, too loaded, when he is in troubles, sins and sorrow.